# xorriso: boot.catalog and -eltorito-catalog not working

Tags: boot, iso, bootable, iso9660

I've been trying to create a bootable CD with `xorriso` by using a custom `boot.catalog` file in order to - that was my goal - specify the LBA my boot sector should be placed at. However, the `xorriso` option `-eltorito-catalog` does not seem to use my custom `boot.catalog`, instead, it creates a new catalog which is then placed in the final ISO image.

My custom `boot.catalog` looks like this (shortened, rest is cleared):

```
 $ xxd boot.catalog | head -n 8
00000000: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 aa55 55aa  .............UU.
00000020: 8800 0000 0000 0400 2000 0000 0000 0000  ........ .......
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
[...]
```

My understanding was that the `DWORD` at `0x00000028` (`2000 0000`, LBA 32) is used to place the boot image at the specified LBA in the bootable CD medium. I am using the following command to create a new bootable ISO image:

```
 $ xorriso -as mkisofs -iso-level 3 -full-iso9660-filenames -eltorito-boot bootimg.bin -eltorito-catalog boot.catalog -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o test2.iso build
```

The resulting ISO image looks as follows:

```
 $ isoinfo -i test2.iso -l -s

Directory listing of /
d---------   0    0    0               1 Mar 17 2020 [     19 02]  . 
d---------   0    0    0               1 Mar 17 2020 [     19 02]  .. 
----------   0    0    0               1 Mar 17 2020 [     33 00]  boot.catalog;1 
----------   0    0    0               1 Mar 17 2020 [     34 00]  bootimg.bin;1 
----------   0    0    0               1 Mar 17 2020 [     35 00]  bootstrap.bin;1
```

As you can see, the `bootimg.bin` boot image is located at LBA 34 (instead of 32, as written in my `boot.catalog`). Also, extracting and dumping the `boot.catalog` from the resulting ISO gives me:

```
 $ xxd boot.catalog | head -n 8
00000000: 0100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 aa55 55aa  .............UU.
00000020: 8800 0000 0000 0400 2200 0000 0000 0000  ........".......
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
[...]
```

My question is, depending on my understanding: Why is the boot image placed at a different sector (and why is my `boot.catalog` being replaced with a new, different one)?

If my understanding of the `-eltorito-catalog` option is wrong: Is there a way to tell `xorriso` where to start writing files at in the ISO image? Are there ways to tell `xorriso` where to place files in the CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `xorriso` actually provides an option which modifies the boot image by placing additional information, like the sector the boot image was loaded from, into a structure which can be accessed from assembly code. The option `-boot-info-table` places a structure at offset `8` which looks like this:

```
DWORD boot_image_pvd
DWORD boot_image_lba
DWORD boot_image_len
DWORD boot_image_checksum
```

The entire structure is written between bytes `8` and `63` in the boot image.

- `boot_image_pvd` is the block of the Primary Volume Descriptor
- `boot_image_lba` is the block where the first 2 KB of the boot image were loaded from
- `boot_image_len` is the length of the entire boot image (in bytes)

More information [here](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/xorriso/xorrisofs.1.en.html).